# How can I load Json data to WebView in Android?

Tags: android, json, android-webview

I am trying to parse JSON data which is in HTML format. I am not understanding how to implement it.

My JsonObject as shown below :

```
{"Content":
{
"PageContent":"<table cellpadding=\"1\" cellspacing=\"0\">\r\n\t<tr><td colspan=\"2\" style=\"font-weight:bold; font-style:italic; font-size:24px; color:Red; text-decoration:blink;\">Contact Us</td></table>"
}
}
```

I want to load jsonobject `i.e. menuPageContent` which is HTML format to WebView.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope you know [how to implement JSON Parsing in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how%20to%20implement%20JSON%20Parsing%20in%20Android)?

Still, here is a way to get `menuPageContent` from above json:

```
String myJSONData = "place your data here";
JSONObject objJSON = new JSONObject(myJSONData);
JSONObject subObj = objJSON.getJSONObject("MenuContent");
String webData = subObj.getString("menuPageContent");

myWebView.loadData(webData, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
```

Read more about [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).

Answer (score 0):

This link will be help to you

http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

webview hav load data and you can use that

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
MyModel model = gson.fromJson("YOUR JSON DATA HERE", MyModel.class);
webView.loadData(model.menuPageContent, "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
```

Comment: sorry, this couldn't help me out. Please check the question. I want to load it to WEBVIEW. The Json I am able to get it.