# Android Wikipedia Article search not display proper in my webview?

Tags: android, html, webview

I am working in Wikipedia-Article search try ing wikipedia API sandbox and geting urls like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox. using this geting url parsing that urls get data that data display in my webview but that data not display in my webview properly.

I want display json data in my webview.That all webview data not fix in my webview,some times my data display out of screen in that time my webview scroll to horizontal.

**EDIT:** Remove horizontal scroll in my webview, data out of screen.

**edit:** Here is my screen-shot ; *I want my webview data display like this*

[image]

but my data display like this only how to solve this issue **without change HTML data because my html data is dynamic**.

**Anyone have any library wikipedia search article** give me some ideas.

[image]

`ANOTHER QUESTION:`How to remove specific `<div>`,`<table>`,`Data` in My Dynamic Html data and how to get `specific word in webview`click(like listview click).
give me any wikipedia library it is very usefull to me.

Can someone please give some hints/suggestions on how this can be done.

Comment: try this solutions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373784/android-how-can-i-load-json-data-to-webview

Answer (score 4):

```
WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
settings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
settings.setLightTouchEnabled(true);
settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

try these setting with your webview, i got my rendering error fixed with this code.